# Replace part of a matrix

Tags: matrix, replacement

I have to generate a `ne` numbers of matrices with `1` and `0` and then replace some elements.

Before I have generated a set of `ZZe[i]` matrices (of only zeros) with `i` from `1` to `ne = 959`

```
nge=6
nn=1082
Table[ZZe[i] = Array[0 &, {nge, nn}],{i,1,ne}]
```

After I have defined the positions inside the `ZZe[i]` where done the replace in this way:

```
    nc=2;    
    Table[{gb1[i] = (nod1[i] - 1)*nc + 1,
    gb2[i] = (nod1[i] - 1)*nc + 2,
    gb3[i] = (nod2[i] - 1)*nc + 1,
    gb4[i] = (nod2[i] - 1)*nc + 2,
    gb5[i] = (nod3[i] - 1)*nc + 1,
    gb6[i] = (nod3[i] - 1)*nc + 2},{i,1,ne}]
```

So now I apply the function `ReplacePart`:

```
Table[ReplacePart[
   ZZe[i], {{1, gb1[i]}, {2, gb2[i]}, {3, gb3[i]}, {4, gb4[i]}, {5, 
      gb5[i]}, {6, gb6[i]}} -> 1], {i, 1, ne}];
```

but it doesn't works well, or rather if I call for example `ZZe[1]` I obtain only a matrix of all zeros.

Can someone tell me where I am getting wrong? I hope even to have written in a correct and easy way to understand!

Comment: Check `SparseArray`, which allows you to efficiently enter non-zero elements into a large matrix.

Comment: Your code doesn't work *for me* because the `nod1`, etc are never defined. `ReplacePart` evidently silently ignores non-numeric part specifications.

Comment: additionally ( and likely your real problem ) , `ReplacePart` doesnt change its argument, bur returns the modified result, you need to do `ZZe[i]=ReplacePart[ZZe[i] , .. ]`

Comment: Thanks to all, I have omitted parts of the code, however nod1[i], etc.. have been defined before!